# Bootstrap toggle AND Ember action simultaniously

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a simple bootstrap/jQuery nav-bar inside an Ember component:

```
<ul class="nav-main">
    <li>
        <a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">Workgroups</a>

            <ul>
              {{#each workgroups as |workgroup|}}
                 <li>
                    {{#link-to 'workgroup' workgroup.id tag='a'}}{{workgroup.label}}{{/link-to}}
                </li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
    </li>
```

til there it's all up and running (submenu is shown).
But now i want to transition to a route (via an action) when clicking on 'Workgroups' to show a list of all workgroups:

```
<a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#" {{action 'transition'}}>Workgroups</a>
```

but this won't fire the ember action at all (not even telling me that nothing handled the action if I provide a wrong name).
Only way to make that action fire is to remove `data-toggle`, which - of course - then would not open the sub menu anymore.

Following some answers here I've tried:

```
// in compenent
didInsertElement: function(){
    Ember.$('[data-toggle=nav-submenu]').click(function(event) {
        console.log('data-toggle was clicked');
        console.log(event);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

This is giving me reasonable output in console, but still won't trigger the action.

So **the question is** if and how I can make both trigger it's action.
One possible workaround I could think of is to trigger the jQuery-Event in my Ember-Action, but this seems quite odd to me (and I wouldn't know how to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, but it feels like a hack, and still doesn't trigger an Ember-action. But it is working for that specific case.

What I did:
I injected the router to the component via an initializer:

```
// app/initializers/component-router-initializer.js
export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.inject('component', 'router', 'router:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'component-router-injector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Then added a route-transition to the jQuery click-event with a custom data-attribute in template:

```
// components/mynavbar.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        let that=this;
        Ember.$('[data-toggle=nav-submenu]').click(function(event) {
            console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.transition);
            that.get('router').transitionTo(event.currentTarget.dataset.transition);
        });
},
```

and in component template

```
// components/mynavbar.hbs
// some other stuff above
<a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" data-transition="workgroups" href="#">Workgroups</a>
// even more stuff below
```

I haven't tested it yet in other browsers than in Chrome, and I will try the other way round (trigger an Ember-action in first place and within that trigger the jQuery-event), but for now it's working somehow.